# vgl.h missing - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vgl

i've started reading the OpenGL Redbook.
They're writing we need the "freeglut" lib. Okay, got it so far.

But they include the "vgl.h" and "LoadShaders.h", it's not included in freeglut?
Where do i find them?

Comment: Ah, they are using their own libaries. They're in the sample source code archiv...
Allright.

Comment: Where is the source archive?

Comment: nvm, you can find it here http://www.opengl-redbook.com/

Comment: A header file in quotes needs to be in the current directory, not the normal include path.  So get the zip package from https://github.com/openglredbook/examples, find vgl.h and LoadShaders.h in it and copy to where your source file is.  Normal includes are in <>, not "".

Answer (score 6):

Go to this [weppage](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/) and click on the link to the right which lets you download the source code.

Then vgl.h is inside the `include` directory when you extract the zip file.

You will also find LoadShaders.h. You will need to add the .cpp implementation file for loadshaders. <s>I haven't found that yet.</s> It is under the `lib` directory.

I had this problem today. Actually I've had the problem for several days. Took me ages to fix it. This version of the redbook isn't quite as easy to get up and running with as the others.

Comment: im running codeblocks - and I just put the lib and include files from their website into the MinGW lib and include folders - still not co-operating w/ me...

Comment: @BenHagel I'm sorry to hear that, when I fixed this problem (a long time ago) I was using Linux, and so I doubt I will be able to help since I know nothing about programming using Windows. Maybe post a new question and include a link in the question to this one? (Since the problem sounds very similar, but isn't a duplicate.)